# Compare values of one column of data table to dynamic number of columns in same table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table "dt" like the following:

```
    a b1 b2 b3 b4     t    t1
 1: 1  4  1  9 NA FALSE  TRUE
 2: 2  5  1  9  2 FALSE  TRUE
 3: 3  6  1  9 NA FALSE FALSE

library(data.table)
dt = setDT(structure(list(a = 1:3, b1 = 4:6, b2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), b3 = c(9L, 
9L, 9L), b4 = c(NA, 2L, NA), t = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), t1 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE)), .Names = c("a", "b1", "b2", "b3", "b4", "t", "t1"
), row.names = c(NA, -3L), class = "data.frame"))
```

I want to create column t1 that is true if row-by-row the value of "a" is in any of the "b" columns such as:

```
dt[,t1 := a %in% c(b1,b2,b3,b4)]
```

However, I'm using this code in a function and the number of b columns may vary, so I'd like to refer to them dynamically.

I've tried something like this:

```
dt[,t := a %in% paste0("b" 1:4)]
```

but it looks for the values of a in the strings "b1", "b2", "b3", or "b4" and returns FALSE.  Is there a way to refer to the columns of a data table dynamically in j?

Comment: It seems that your code does not respect the "row-by-row" condition. E.g. if `dt$a[3] = 2`, then `dt$t1[3]` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Could also try something like `melt(dt, id = "a", measure.vars = patterns("b"))[!is.na(value), any(value == .BY[[1L]]), by = a]`

Answer (score 1):

This does what you want. It uses the `grepl` function to grab the column numbers in which the column name has a `b` in its first character. Then you use those column indexes to test whether the `a` column value is equal to any of those in the `b` columns.

Sum across the Boolean results of that comparison (avoiding `NA` values) and test for the sum > 0 (telling us that at least one value was TRUE) and assign those values to the `t1` column.

This also has the virtue (if it is one) that the `b` columns do not have to be contiguous.

```
bcols = which(grepl('^b', names(dt)))
dt$t1 = apply((dt$a == dt[,bcols]), 1, sum, na.rm=T) > 0
```

Comment: Why would you run an inefficient by row loop for such simple vectorized operation?  Why not just `rowSums(dt[, "a"] == dt[, bcols], na.rm = TRUE) > 0`?

Comment: Good point. I just "blurted" my first thought. I appreciate the refinement.

Comment: dt[,bcols] doesn't seem to pull up the subtable.  It just creates a vector of the column numbers

Comment: @wellshux This answer uses data.frame syntax. You can use `dt[, bcols, with=FALSE]` there or change your data.table to data.frame first, with `setDF`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt where you can use `.SDcols` to specify `b1:bn` columns, and then compare their values to that in the `a` column:

```
dt[, Reduce(`+`, lapply(.SD, function(x) x==a & (!is.na(x)) )) > 0, .SDcols=b1:b4]
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Where `dt` was:

```
dt <- data.table(a = 1:3, b1 = 4:6, b2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), b3 = c(9L, 
9L, 9L), b4 = c(NA, 2L, NA), t = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE), t1 = c(TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE))
```

Comment: Or `dt[, rowSums(.SD  == dt$a, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, .SDcols = b1:b4]` :) But I guess it's not so idiomatic

Comment: @DavidArenburg - I doubt `rowSums` causes any huge slowdown but I always try to stick to `list` like objects in `data.table` if I can. I thought I had a benchmark of this somewhere but I can't find it for the life of me.

Comment: Instead of `Reduce`, I guess `pmax` fits: `dt[, as.logical(do.call(pmax,c(lapply(.SD, \`==\`, a), na.rm=TRUE))), .SDcols=b1:b4]`

Comment: @Frank - nice. I like it.